# How do I find which Material UI default theme label will change the default border color (not focus or hover border)?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using 'createTheme' to customize the theme of my TextField input from Material UI.

To make the changes I am looking at the Material UI default theme on https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/ and making changes to the appropriate labels.

I want to change the default border of the TextField - the border that appears when there is no hover or focus on the TextField. The border is currently grey

Does anyone know which default theme label refers to that border? I can't seem to find it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use inline styling inside a textfield.
`<TextField style={{ border:"1px solid color name", }}/>`

Comment: it will override the default border.

Answer (score 0):

I used it on main layout :

```
   const useStyles = makeStyles(() => (
    {
        root: {

                "& .css-h5voop-MuiInputBase-root-MuiInput-root:before": {
            borderBottom:" 1px solid rgb(215 50 50 / 70%)",
                },

     }
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a good way and you can use !important to be sure it works

```
const theme = createTheme({

 components: {
    MuiInputBase: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "&:before":{
            borderBottom:"1px solid yellow ",}
        },
      },
    },
  },

})
```